# Is it okay to use the quadratic equation in an inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been trying to solve this problem:

A chicken cost $38$ units. The weekly cost of preparing $x$ chickens is given by the equation: $P = -0.1x^2 + 1190 + 28x$. How many chickens must be sold weekly not to lose money?

What I have:

$$WeeklySales - WeeklyCost > 0$$

$$WeeklyCost = -0.1x^2 + 28x + 1190$$

$$WeeklySales = 38x$$

Solving, I get:

$$ 38x - 28x + 0.1x^2 - 1190 > 0$$

$$(1/10)x^2 + 10x - 1190 > 0$$

Should I use the quadratic equation here?

**UPDATE1**:

I want to use the quadratic equation because I cannot factor the last expression. Any hint is welcome. Note that $1190 = (2)(5)(7)(17)$.

**UPDATE2**:

Solving it with the quadratic equation I get:$x_1 = 70$ and $x_2 = -170$.

But multiplying them, gives: **-11900** (notice the negative sign and the extra "0").

$$x_1 = \frac{-(10) + \sqrt[2]{(100) - 4(1/10)(-1190)}}{(2)(1/10)}$$

$$x_1 = 70$$

$$x_2 = \frac{-(10) - \sqrt[2]{(100) - 4(1/10)(-1190)}}{(2)(1/10)}$$

$$x_2 = -170$$

What should I do?

Comment: You're right that the quadratic equation is the right way to go - factoring is typically best when you have smaller coefficients. When you use the quadratic equation, though, it will give you the $x$ values that makes the expression you plug in exactly zero. In between those values, the expression will either be positive or negative. By plugging in values in between, you can find out whether each region is positive or negative and get your answer.

Comment: $2\times 2 \times 5 \times 59 = 1180$

Comment: Now that you know the roots are 70 and -170, the factoization is $\frac{1}{10}(x-70)(x+170)$.

Comment: But i took the $1/10$ as the $a$ element in the quadratic equation. And doing sdo gave me $70$ and $-170$. And $(70)  * (- 170) =  11900$ notice the extra $0$.

Comment: $$\frac1{10}(70)(-170)=-1190.$$

Answer (score 2):

The quadratic formula will tell you the values of $x$ with the property that the quantity is *equal* to zero.  Since the particular quadratic expression you are looking at is an upward-pointing parabola, it will take on negative values between those two $x$ values, and positive values outside those two $x$ values.

Answer (score 0):

The quadratic formula will tell you where equality with $0$ occurs. In particular, at all other points, it is either greater than $0$ or less than $0$ (and it must remain the same sign unless it cross another $0$, so this reduces your work to just testing three points).

Answer (score 0):

You can't just write out the quadratic equation with a $>$ instead of a $=$, but that's definitely the right tool.

Say you have $ax^2 + bx + c > 0$. The quadratic equation will give you $x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$. Call those two values $x_1$ and $x_2$. One way to think about it is that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the two solutions to the equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$.

But the other way to think about it is in terms of factors: $ax^2 + bx + c = a(x - x_1)(x - x_2)$. This should tell you how to proceed with your inequality.

Comment: Please, elaborate more about your answer. In the "but" part... you use $=$ and not $>$. Why?

Comment: What did you do with quadratics before you learned the quadratic formula? You probably factored them. That's what I'm doing here. For example, consider $x^2 - 5x + 6$: if you use the quadratic formula, you get $3$ and $2$. Notice that $x^2 - 5x + 6 = (x - 3)(x - 2)$. That's not a coincidence. :)

Comment: See my update, please.

Comment: Ah, I think I get where you're stuck. Using the quadratic equation and factoring the quadratic are the same thing!

To factor a quadratic, you can either guess-and-check (can fail, but is sometimes faster), or you can use the quadratic formula to find the roots. Say we successfully factored our quadratic: $ax^2 + bx + c = a(x - \alpha)(x - \beta)$. Then clearly $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are solutions to $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$. So they must come from the quadratic equation!

Comment: And if you don't believe me, try expanding the following expression: $$ a \left(x - \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} \right) \left(x - \frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} \right) $$

Answer (score 0):

Yeah just find solution of the quadratic equation with =0.
You will get two answers.

Suppose a,b are answers

Check the inequality equation for

1) < a condition

2) > b condition

3) BTW a&b condition.

**Example**

Suppose 3,5 are answers

Test inequality with

1) < 3 take a number lesser than 3 maybe 2 etc...

2) > 5 take a number greater than 5 maybe 7 etc...

3) BTW 3&5 take a number between 3 & 5 maybe 4 etc...

If it satisfies 1&3 conditions answer is 3

Answer (score 0):

You use the root-finding formulas to factor the polynomial.

$$ax^2+bx+c>0$$becomes $$a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)>0,$$ where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the real roots.

Then for the product to be positive, the number of negative factors must be even (odd for $<$).

If there are no real roots, the polynomial has the sign of $a$.

---

In your example,

$$\frac1{10}(x-170)(x+70)>0$$
requires either
$$x>170\text{ and }x>-70 \text{ (no negative)}$$or$$x<170\text{ and }x<-70 \text{ (two negatives)}.$$

and this amounts to $$x>170\text{ or }x<-70.$$